# How to explicit include a component to be autowiried in Spring?

Tags: java, spring

I created an api toolkit with lots of classes that I want to share to several projects.
Some projects run in a tomcat environment, some are just comand line tools.

Thus, I'd like to include some specific classes on the tomcat projects, and exclude them in the cmd tools. Eg:

```
package my.base;

@Component
@WebListener
public class OrderlyShutdown extends ContextLoaderListener {

}
```

This is of course only to be included in tomcat. Is there a way I can tell my `@Configuration` class to include or exclude certain classes (not by package name!)?

Comment: The _explicit_ way of including a bean is to use a `<bean>` declaration or `@Bean` method in a `@Configuration` class. Get rid of the `@Component` and declare the beans you want explicitly in your configuration.

Comment: You can use [filters to customize the scanning process](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-scanning-filters) and using regular expressions or "custom" filter you can include or exclude certain beans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Since Spring 3.1 you can use [`@Profile`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.3.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Profile.html) to include or exclude certain components based on a list of active profiles:

  ```
  @Component
  @WebListener
  @Profile("tomcat")
  public class OrderlyShutdown extends ContextLoaderListener { ... }
  ```
- Since Spring 4.0 you can also use [`@Conditional`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.3.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Conditional.html) for more fine-grained control